# Making a walkie talkie wpf application

Tags: wpf, audio

I've been really interested in making a walkie talkie wpf application, however I'm not too sure where to start. I was wondering what kind of technology would be needed to capture one person speaking and playing it back to someone else? Any resources available online to learn about the technology required etc. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's interested in something like this too, I found that the makers of Zello the phone walkie talkie phone app also provide a SDK which can be used to integrate in a .NET application. It's also free for up to 5 people on your network. So I'm going to check it out and see how I can implement it in my app. Here's the link for anyone who's interested http://zello.com/sdk.htm